Integrate: $\int_{a}^{b}(rdr)^2$
I stumbled upon this when finding center of mass of solid hemisphere in physics. It is anyways a nice problem on its own I think.
The question is how would you compute an integral of the following form?
$$
\int_{a}^{b}(rdr)^2
$$
My guess would be doing it with parametric curves or just dividing and multiplying by $dr$ (which might now work).

Please format your equations correctly using Mathjax. It is very hard to understand what you are asking. Also, please show some effort as to what you have tried and where you are stuck. As to findding the center of mass of a solid hemisphere, there are numerous resources on the web that you will find helpful.

It's not really well posed, but if you had to give it a meaning I believe it would just end up as $\frac13 r^3 dr$.

What reference gave this? I feel it should be like $r^2 \ dr.$

Unless you're in the world of differential forms, I don't know how to interpret $(dr)^2$.

@CalebStanford Um sir did you mean just $\frac 13 r^3$ without the $dr$?

@Randall I want know what would ∫rdr dr mean?
More like ∫r(dr)^2 or that type
